# unset Authorization header in varnish but also send the header to backend

Tags: authorization, varnish, varnish-vcl

I want to remove the Authorization header in varnish vcl but also needs this header to be sent to back-end as well.

```
sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.Authorization;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bad idea, but it's definitely doable using some basic VCL. For example:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.Authorization) {
        set req.http.Authorization-Copy = req.http.Authorization;
        unset req.http.Authorization;
    } else {
        unset req.http.Authorization-Copy;
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    if (bereq.http.Authorization-Copy) {
        set bereq.http.Authorization = bereq.http.Authorization-Copy;
        unset bereq.http.Authorization-Copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: As Carlos said - it seems like a bad idea. If the response gets cached then every next request will see the "authorized" response data - even without authorization.

Comment: @Ronald this issue can be easily circumvented by `hash`-ing on `req.http.Authorization-Copy`